# POST String Decoding in PHP

Tags: php, decoding

Is ther any built in function in PHP to decode

przysi%25C4%2599gam%2520s%25C5%2582u%25C5%25BCy%25C4%2587

into

przysięgam służyć

?

Comment: Are you sure, that the program generating these strings knows what it's doing? If it is an UTF-8 url encoded string, it should read `przysi%25%C4%25%99gam...`, that is, with both bytes url-encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Gordon and Manos, you're both right (and both wrong ;)

It's just normal 'urldecode', but applied *twice*

```
$a = "przysi%25C4%2599gam%2520s%25C5%2582u%25C5%25BCy%25C4%2587";
$b = urldecode(urldecode($a));
var_dump($b);
```

Comment: This is interesting, because the String is being posted a mortal JS script using encodeURLEntity() -- no idea why the stuff is encoded twice then

Answer (score 2):

[urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) — Decodes URL-encoded string

But I think that won't work on multibyte strings. See the comments on the manual page for possible userland workarounds and also http://www.zend.com//code/codex.php?ozid=839&single=1

Comment: Negative. Urldecode fails on that one badly, as it decodes only %## characters.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have issues with urldecode and multibyte characters. Urldecode can only decode 8 bit characters and your string contains multibyte characters.

Check the [urldecode manual page comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) for some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
    function utf8_urldecode($str) {
      $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
      return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
```

Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Edit: Your initial string is messed up. Did you urlencode it twice? Cause utf8_urldecode(utf8_urldecode($encoded string)) gives the correct result.

Comment: gave `przysi%C4%99gam%20s%C5%82u%C5%BCy%C4%87` on my machine.